# Адаптация фонового изображения между экранами

Tags: html, css

Есть такой сайт: topbud.in.ua
На компьютере фоновое изображение выглядит хорошо, когда я смотрю через режим адаптивного дизайна выглядит кривовато, но терпимо, но когда открываю сайт через гаджеты (iPad Air 2, iPhone SE) - фон ломается.

```
.header {
  background-image: url(data/images/main.png);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 90vh;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Советую ознакомиться с медиа запросами для css стилей, они позволят вам изменять стили в зависимости от разрешения экрана пользователя, чтобы вы могли подогнать верстку под мобильные устройства и наоборот. https://html5book.ru/css3-mediazaprosy/

Answer (score -1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
     .header {
          background-attachment- scroll;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Это не работает